# How to fit JSON.parse into Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, json, promise

I got this code to retrieve a batch of matches from Riot Games League of Legends API:

```
const matches = await Promise.all(matchlist.matches.map(function(match){
    return qRequest(server, "/match/v3/matches/" + match.gameId);
}));
```

The return value is a JSON formatted String. So `matches` ends up beeing an array of JSON Strings. I need the JSON parsed though, so that matches is an array of objects.

I just can't wrap my head around how to fit JSON.parse in here?

Comment: Why are you using `Promise.all`, do you have multiple promises?

Comment: @MrAlb: The OP knows about `JSON.parse`. They don't know how to apply it here: *"I just can't wrap my head around how to fit JSON.parse in here?"*

Comment: @FelixKling yes you are right, i voted up to your answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to `matches`

```
let matches = ... ;
matches = matches.map(json => JSON.parse(json));
```

or call `JSON.parse` inline:

```
const matches = await Promise.all(matchlist.matches.map(function(match){
  return qRequest(server, "/match/v3/matches/" + match.gameId)
    .then(json => JSON.parse(json));
}));
```

Comment: I was aware of the possibility to map it again afterwards, but I thought there must be a more elegant way instead of mapping twice. The second one looks good.